# How to globaly access server's mysql DB

Tags: mysql, windows

I want to access my server's MySql database in my local system. But I am unable to set/configure server's mysql to allow remote access. Please tell me that how can i configure server.

Comment: You need to provide us with more information to know how to help you. For example, what is the error message you got when trying to connect remotely? What do you mean by remotely (within same LAN or over Internet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must need to change setting in Windows Firewall-

1. Open Windows Firewall
2. click on "Allow a program or feature through windows firewall"
3. Click on MySql in list and set/mark public/access anywhere then click ok.

Then you may access this db in local system.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't much clear. Usually if you want to access your MySql db only locally you must create a user with the Host field set to localhost, and if you want to access from everywhere the host value must be set to "%" otherwise you can specify the hosts like in that example:

INSERT INTO user (Host,User,Password,...)
    VALUES('%.mydomain.com','myname',PASSWORD('pass'),...);
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

where % indicate from any host from mydomain.com

Comment: we have tried but "%" supports only in linux server does not in wondows server.